# Redirect to controller's action using name of the model's class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
def redirect
  redirect_to [:new, Object::const_get(params[:type_of_place])]
end
```

For example, params[:type_of_place] can store 'bar'. I hoped that it could redirect me to the 'new' action of the 'bars' controller, but it couldn't. How can I fix it? Is it possible to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure which model to use in #new, you can use `redirect_to send("new_#{user_input}_path")`. No need to use params and switch.

Comment: redirect is a sample name :) I must be able to set any name for type_of_place, therefore I can't use constant path helper as 'new_bar_path'. Can I generate helper?

Comment: I'm still not aware of the use case, as well as why you can't use named path. Could you elaborate more in question?

Comment: I can't use named_path as "new_bar_path", because I don't know what user can send in advance. For example, he can send 'bar', or 'club', or something else. I can use 'switch' for it, but I hope to generate path helper without it.

Comment: If you are not sure which model to use in #new, you can use `redirect_to send("new_#{user_input}_path")`. No need switch.

Comment: thanks man! it works. edit your answer and I'll make it as 'right'

Comment: My pleasure :) Revised.